# Prevent access to constructor / only specific class has access

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, software-design

Let's say I have an `Apple Class` and an `AppleFactory`Class.
Nobody should be able to use `Apple redApple = new Apple()`. Instead new Apples should only be able to be created from  `AppleFactory.Create()`.

This mean the Constructor of Apple must be inaccessible for everyone but the AppleFactory Class.

How can this be done?

EDIT: `Apple` is more like an `AppleModel`. So there is only Properties in there.

Comment: You're looking for something similar to the friend relationship from C++, which is not available in C#.

If I may offer an opinion, you shouldn't be worrying about this.  If somebody in future wants to create an instance of Apple themselves then that it their issue, not yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *a different type* to act as the factory, then the closest you can get is `internal`:

```
public sealed class Apple() {
    internal Apple() {} 
}
public class AppleFactory() {
    public Apple CreateApple() => new Apple();
}
```

However, if you can have the factory as a static method on `Apple`, then you can keep everything `private`:

```
public sealed class Apple() {
    private Apple() {} 
    public static Apple Create() => new Apple();
}
```

Comment: Problem is the Apple is more like an AppleModel. So there's only Properties in there, no real Logic. I'd rather not put the Factory inside Apple itself.

Comment: @Thypari I hear you; I'm just telling you what the options are :) Note - if this `Apple` is from code-gen tools: `partial class` may help - allows you to add functionality to a class in a separate file. Similarly: extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can let the `Apple` class be its own factory.

```
public class Apple
{
    private Apple()
    {}

    internal static Apple Create()
    {
        var apple = new Apple();
        // TODO: Initialize
        return apple;
    }
}
```

The real Apple factory can then call this factory method:

```
public class AppleFactory() {
    public CreateApple() => Apple.Create();
}
```

By making `Apple.Create()` internal, you can restrict its usage to the current assembly. The constructor can be called only insde `Apple` anway, because it is `private`.

Comment: Problem is the Apple is more like an AppleModel. So there's only Properties in there, no real Logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Apple` abstract, then make a `private` subclass inside `AppleFactory`.

However, you can't prevent other people from making their own subclasses.